# ¿Cómo se dice «best way»?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

Creo que "best way" en inglés es informal. Es una frase para indicar algo con prudencia.  Creo que es eso.

Pero en español, ¿cómo se dice?

Lo siento por mi español, aún no sé mucho. ¡Estoy aprendiendo!

Comment: No creo que *best way* sea informal. *That's the best way to do it* para mí, como anglohablante nativo, es perfectamente adecuado para registros formales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Best way* podría traducirse como *la mejor manera* o *la mejor forma*.

> Is that the best way to do it? / Es esa la **mejor manera** de hacerlo?

*Prudente* como en `Es la manera más prudente de hacerlo` equivaldría a `Is the most sensible way to do it`.

Si puedes poner usos de "best way", sería más fácil darte una respuesta en contexto para esos usos.

Por cierto, en lugar de "lo creo que" decimos "es lo que creo". Está muy bien que intentes practicar español siempre que puedas. Bravo!!

Comment: A menos que esté hablando de una jerga particular (y desconocida por mí), no hace falta más contexto, tienes toda la razón.

Answer (score 1):

For example, this question: What is the best way to do it?

You can translate it as:

> ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo?

or

> ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de hacerlo?

By the way, you did some mistakes and remember that everyone has to start from the beginning with any thing. I'm still learning english!

> Creo que "best way" en inglés es informal. Es una frase para indicar algo con 
>   prudencia. Creo que es eso.
>
> Pero en español, ¿cómo se dice?
>
> Lo siento por mi español, aún no sé mucho. ¡Estoy aprendiendo!

Since I've just registered in this website, I couldn't write you a message directly, it's necessary to write on this way. Diego's answer was perfect.

Daniel.

Comment: Welcome. FYI: you cannot send a message anyway. It doesn't matter how long you've been part of the community. What you will be able to do is suggesting edits (I don't know how much, if any, rep is necessary though). I did this now, so once the suggestions are accepted, the question contains your improvements and your answer is reduced to the essential part.

Answer (score 0):

> > > > La mejor manera<<<<<

EJEMPLO:

The best way to resolve the issue remains diplomatic negotiations.

> > La mejor manera de resolver la cuestión siguen siendo las negociaciones
> >     diplomáticas